Toggle Eye Icon for Password Visibility in SfTextBox for .NET MAUI Blazor
I am using the SfTextBox in a .NET MAUI Blazor application to create a password field with an eye icon to toggle password visibility. My goal is to change the icon from an "eye" to an "eye-slash" (or similar) whenever the user clicks to show/hide the password.
<SfTextBox
    ID="passwordBox"
    @ref="TextBoxPasswordObj"
    @bind-Value="_tokenModel.Password"
    ValueChange="@PasswordValueChangeHandler"
    Input="@PasswordInputHandler"
    Type="@TextBoxType"
    CssClass="input-box"
    Placeholder="Password"
    Created="@AddPwdIcon"
    Destroyed="AddPwdIconDestroyed"
    FloatLabelType="@FloatLabelType.Auto"
    @onkeydown="OnPasswordInputKeyDown"
></SfTextBox>

public async void AddPwdIcon() { 
  // Adding the eye icon initially 
  await TextBoxPasswordObj.AddIconAsync("append", "e-icons e-eye", new  Dictionary<string, object>()
  { { "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>(this, PasswordClick) } 
  }); 
}

public async Task PasswordClick() {
  await _JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("showhidePassword", "passwordBox"); IsPasswordVisible = !IsPasswordVisible;
}

// JavaScript
function showhidePassword(textBoxId) {
    const textBox = document.getElementById(textBoxId);
    const icon = textBox.parentElement.querySelector('.e-input-group-icon');
    icon.classList.toggle('fa-eye');
    icon.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
}

The problem is that the icon does not change when I click on it to show or hide the password. I’ve used e-eye and fa-eye-slash classes, assuming they would toggle correctly, but the icon remains the same.
I want to change the icon after clicking it

The selector is strange. You could try following sample

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<SfTextBox ID="passwordBox" @ref="TextBoxObj" Type="@TextBoxType" Placeholder="Enter Password" Created="@Created"></SfTextBox>

<script>
    function showhidePassword(textBoxId) {
        const textBox = document.getElementById(textBoxId);
        const icon = textBox.parentElement.querySelector('.e-icons');
        icon.classList.toggle('e-eye');
        icon.classList.toggle('e-eye-slash');
    }
</script>

@code {
    SfTextBox TextBoxObj;
    bool IsPasswordVisible = false;
    InputType TextBoxType => IsPasswordVisible ? InputType.Text : InputType.Password;

    public async Task Created()
    {
        await TextBoxObj.AddIconAsync("append", "e-icons e-eye-slash", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>(this, PasswordClick) } });
    }

    public async Task PasswordClick()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("showhidePassword", "passwordBox");
        IsPasswordVisible = !IsPasswordVisible;
    }
}

